# msiexec /qn Switch Prevents Uninstall

Tags: c#, windows-installer, silent-installer

I'm trying to uninstall an application via C# using the following call:

```
msiexec.exe /x {my-product-code} /qn
```

Without the `/qn` switch, a dialog would appear asking if you want to uninstall. The `/qn` switch suppresses this dialog, but it appears to also cause an implicit "*No*" for the dialog result, because the application does not uninstall. If I leave off the `/qn` switch, I get the dialog as expected and if I choose "*Yes*", the application uninstalls.

How can I use the `/qn` switch without it causing an implicit "*No*" to the confirmation?

Comment: If you add logging, what does the log file say before the uninstall quits? "msiexec.exe /x {my-product-code} /qn /l*v uninstall.log"

Comment: I suspect that the uninstall requires privilege and your program isn't elevated. Even if it is elevated, don't shell out the uninstall - I'd use MsiConfigureProductEx() directly to make sure you are transferring your privilege to the uninstall. Apart from that, add a /L*v [path to text log] to the uninstall command line and see what's going on. The problem is unlikely to be an implicit No!!

Comment: After logging, I found the issue was with not having elevated privileges as PhilDW said. This only happens when using the /qn switch, because there is no administrative confirmation for uninstall. I'm still shelling it out, but am now adding StartInfo.UsernName, along with StartInfo.UseShellExecute. Thanks for the direction, it was exactly what I needed.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

As PhilDW noted in the comment above, the issue was one of needing to elevate privileges. Even though I'm an administrator, using the /qn switch suppresses the confirmation dialog (as expected), and the confirmation dialog is used as the administrative confirmation that it's OK to uninstall. The solution was as follows:

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "msiexec.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("/x {0} /qn /l*v uninstall.log", productCode);
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true; // added to elevate privileges
process.StartInfo.Verb = "runas"; // added to elevate privileges
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```